# How to grant sendmail permission to sql server user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database user which is the owner of the database. The application requirement is to send mail using database mail of sql server .

Is there any way that I can add grant only send mail permission to that user?

I have a user named testuser having server roles **public** and is **db_owner** for 1 database. Please tell me the way that I don`t need to give sysadmin serverroles to that user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try with the below 2 options.

```
USE msdb;
--add our user
CREATE USER  ClarkKent FOR LOGIN  ClarkKent; 
--give this user rights to use dbmail
exec sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'ClarkKent'
```

now if we know ClarkKent is getting his authorization from a windows group, then you add that windows group as a user, and add that group to the same role;

```
USE msdb;
--add our user via a group we know he is in 
CREATE USER 'mydomain\BusinessGroup' FOR LOGIN   'mydomain\BusinessGroup'; 
--give this GROUP rights to use dbmail
exec sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'mydomain\BusinessGroup'
```

Comment: Highlight text and use the "Code sample" icon to format text as code. Code sample icon looks like `{}`.

Comment: I have tried this but still unable to use database mail service .

Comment: I am getting below message **The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sysmail_help_profile_sp', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)**

Answer (score 4):

[image]

you need add 'DatabasemailUserRole' for MSDB database to user

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the login (or a role) to the mail profile after adding it to the database mail role.  For the script below, a default of one may need to be set, instead of zero.

```
use msdb
exec sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'sqlUser'

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
@principal_name = 'sqlUser',  
@profile_name = 'sqlMailProfileName',
@is_default = 0
```